# How to select mysql rows based off time increment adjustments (vb mysql)

Tags: mysql, vb.net, select

I'm using the following select statement to pull rows of data and display them in a datagrid

```
    SELECT 
a.tmc, w.date, a.surface_temperature, 
a.air_temperature, a.material_rate, 
a.time, w.intensity 
FROM application a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN weather w 
ON a.DATE = w.DATE AND a.tmc = w.tmc 
WHERE w.DATE = '" & calendar1.SelectedDate & "' 
AND w.event= '" & weatherType.SelectedItem.Value & "' 
AND w.City = '" & sender.CssClass & "'
```

This displays sometimes 5,000 different rows of data with one of the columns being time. Their times are something along the lines of 6:08, 6:09, etc. Is there a way I can show only 1 row for all times between 6-6:59?

The rows should look something like this

```
Time  Temp
1:00   27
2:00   31
3:00   32
```

Thanks!

Comment: What temperature value are you going to display in this case? Average, Max, Min, Sum?

Comment: That string concatenation makes your code vulnerable to sql injection. use query parameters instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magic little expression

```
CONVERT(DATE_FORMAT(w.DATE,'%Y-%m-%d-%H:00:00'),DATETIME)
```

will give back w.DATE with the minutes and seconds zeroed out.

For example,

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE_FORMAT('1941-12-07 08:45:20',
                           '%Y-%m-%d-%H:00:00'
                          ),DATETIME)
```

returns `1941-12-07 08:00:00`.

Without trying to figure out all the logic of your query (other stuff is going on there that I don't understand) here's a way to get an hourly summary of  weather observations.

```
SELECT station, 
       CONVERT(DATE_FORMAT(observation_time,'%Y-%m-%d-%H:00:00'),DATETIME) observation_hour,
       MIN(temperature) min_temp,
       MAX(temperature) max_temp,
       AVG(temperature) avg_temp
  FROM observation
 GROUP BY station, CONVERT(DATE_FORMAT(observation_time,'%Y-%m-%d-%H:00:00'),DATETIME)
 ORDER BY station, CONVERT(DATE_FORMAT(observation_time,'%Y-%m-%d-%H:00:00'),DATETIME)
```

The GROUP BY expression turns this into a summary query, summarizing hour by hour.

Be careful.  Your `DATE` columns seem to actually contain `DATETIME` data types.   Your join on `a.DATE=w.DATE` insists that the date and time in those columns of your `application` and `weather` table rows be precisely identical.  Is that true?  Giving a `DATETIME` column the name `DATE` could be misleading to the next programmer who works on this database.